# How to clean organization?

Tags: deployment, organization-wide

I want to delete all custon things (custom objects, pages, Apex classes, trigers and so on) by using Ant build tool. How can I implement It. My **`destructiveChanges.xml`** looks like:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
     <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

But I have error

> All Component Failures:
>   1.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No ApexTrigger named: * found
>   2.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No ApexPage named: * found
>   3.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomObject named: * found
>   4.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No ApexClass named: * found`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `destructiveChanges.xml` file won't let you use wildcards (*).  You'll need to specify every single item you want deleted.

i.e.

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ReasonableClass</members>
        <members>ReasonableClassTest</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>MyObject__c</members>
        <members>AntoherObject__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

See also: [Deleting Files from an Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

> To delete files, create a delete manifest that’s called destructiveChanges.xml. The format of the delete manifest is the same as package.xml, except that wildcards aren’t supported.

If you're comfortable with ant, you can also use the [listMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_listmetadata.htm) and [describeMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_describemetadata.htm) targets that are supplied in the sample build file to get the many elements that you may want to include in the destructiveChanges.xml file.  They won't return the values in an overly friendly form, so you'll need to get the results and find a way to turn it into xml.